Creating a Json parameter file and reading using powershell
I have got a powershell script that reads the following information from within a Ps custom object, at this point I would like to split out the code from the parameters, the idea is to use a json file with the definition and then have a Ps script file that reads from the json file and loops through to apply permissions.
The below is a tabular representation of the data.

After reading from the json file it will then loop to apply the values derived from the json files replacing the role, type and objectID
  $id = az synapse role assignment list --workspace-name syn-auto-inf-dev --role "<role>" --assignee-object-id "<object_id>" --query "[?principalId=='<object_id>']" | ConvertFrom-Json 
  if ($null -eq $id.principalId)
  {
    
    az synapse role assignment create --workspace-name "my-workspace" --role "Synapse Administrator" --assignee-principal-type "<type>" --assignee-object-id "<object-id>" 
    
  }

what do i need help with ?

representing the data in a json format
reading the json and looping through extracting the fields role,
type and objectID



Use ConvertTo-Json to create your JSON file from [pscustomobject] instances:
# Create your JSON file
@(
  [pscustomobject] @{ Role = 'Administrator'; Type = 'Group'; ObjectID = '982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e' },
  [pscustomobject] @{ Role = 'Reader'; Type = 'ServicePrincipal'; ObjectID = '4ed0-ac15-d52f357f' }
) | ConvertTo-Json > objects.json

You can then read this JSON file with ConvertFrom-Json, which converts the JSON back into [pscustomobject] instances, and use their properties as arguments in your az calls:
# Read your JSON file and process each object,
# referring to the one at hand with $_ and accessing its properties,
# e.g. $_.Role
(Get-Content -Raw objects.json | ConvertFrom-Json) |
  ForEach-Object {
    $id = az synapse role assignment list --workspace-name syn-auto-inf-dev --role $_.Role --assignee-object-id $_.ObjectId --query "[?principalId=='$($_.ObjectId)']" | ConvertFrom-Json
    if ($null -eq $id.principalId) {      
      az synapse role assignment create --workspace-name 'my-workspace' --role 'Synapse Administrator' --assignee-principal-type $_.Type --assignee-object-id $_.ObjectID
    }        
  }

Note:

The ConvertFrom-Json call is enclosed in (...) to make Windows PowerShell enumerate the parsed-from-JSON [pscustomobject] instances in the pipeline, i.e, to send them one by one; fortunately, PowerShell (Core) 7 now does this by default (you can ask for the old behavior of outputting an array as a single object with -NoEnumerate).

Each [pscustomobject] is processed with ForEach-Object, which accepts a script block inside of which the automatic $_ variable refers to the input object at hand.

Note that passing stand-alone property references as command arguments - such as $_.Role - does not need quoting in PowerShell (even if the property values happen to contains spaces).

By contrast, if they are to be embedded in a larger string, you must use "...", i.e. an expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string, and you must enclose the property reference (due to being an expression) in $(...), the subexpression operator, e.g. "[?principalId=='$($_.ObjectId)']"



